# How to compress video in android?

Tags: android, video

I am developing an application that allows users to capture video for maximum 2min. The user can upload the video to server after that. I need to compress the video before I am posting it to server. How do I compress the video ?

Comment: Try to create Custom video recorder and put Low Resoultion  to Cameara , then u can decrease 98% of memory

Comment: You can compress mp4 files using a library.
Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23815402/4153725

Comment: Check out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24324852/how-to-compress-video-file-in-android/42887536#42887536

Answer (score 0):

It already is compressed, whether you are using `MPEG_4` or `THREE_GPP`.

Comment: i am recording in mpeg_4. is it possible to compress it again to another suitable format so that it will be easy for me to send it to a server. Since it largely depends on the network speed, it will be good if i can compress it as much as i can.

Comment: @user1002448: MP4 should be adequately compressed. Android has no support for de-compressing and re-compressing a video. Your file size is much more dependent upon your chosen size, frame rate, etc.

Comment: @CommonsWare: is there any update for the same? I want to compress the video in android.